# Django: Need a way to restrict user to view media one after the other [after completing first video then second video has to enable otherwise not]

Tags: django

Requirement: I want to design a portal, where user can read/view media [eg: documents/ videos]. Let us suppose I have 10 documents which I will show in a web page. I want to make sure that user reads the first document then only second document will be available to read otherwise we have to disable the link.

Comment: You can have an intermediate table which tracks the user and the completed videos. Example `(user, video_num)`. Deny access if the user tries to access a video link they are not supposed to.

Comment: if you give the model structure means it will great for explain , my assumption based on authenticated user if the user foreign key in the Video model, put a Boolean field is_view = default (false) , once the user click Video make the is_view true then show next video else show the same video